# Why are Web browsers sticking to 32-bit?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, 64-bit

64-bit architectures are out for quite a long time now and most software applications have made the move already but Web browsers are staying behind.

Within the major competitors, Microsoft is the only vendor I know of providing a stable 64-bit version of [Internet Explorer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/internet-explorer-11-for-windows-7-details.aspx) and [Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48126).

Mozilla, Google and Opera are for now only providing an unstable version of their browser with 64-bit support.

What is the blocking point for Web browsers to switch to 64-bit?

Comment: What's the benefit of switching to 64-bit?

Comment: All the major browsers are currently 64-bit.  So its not clear what the purpose of this question is.  Chrome and Firefox both are offering **stable** 64-bit releases.  Chrome has been offering it for over a year, while Firefox 42, is the first stable 64-bit version of Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, most browsers are moving (slowly) to 64 bit (see [here](http://www.ghacks.net/2015/10/17/fingers-crossed-firefox-64-bit-for-windows-to-be-released-when-firefox-42-comes-out/) about Firefox and [here](http://www.omgchrome.com/install-google-chrome-64-bit-windows/) about Chrome). Probably it taken so much time (Firefox still not public by now, Chrome download defaults to 32 bit, and 64 is still marked as beta), beside the various bugs they had to solve, because *maybe* they didn't find it to deserve so much attention. I'm not into browsers development but i may guess that, at the moment, advantages are few and not worthing all the effort. 32 bits are still widely supported, after all, and most of plugins are in 32 bits, and even if the operating system is at 64 it works just good with 32 stuff. Why run? I'm absolutely sure if this was a priority we had all major browsers at 64 bits **years** ago :)